# How to delete spaces in string and write first letter uppercase?

Tags: haskell, space, uppercase, fold

I am trying to delete every space between words and uppercase every letter of a word with foldr.

I have tried it with map:

```hs
deleteSpaces:: String -> String
deleteSpaces word = (filter(not . isSpace) .unwords . map (\(x:xs) -> (toUpper x):xs) . words) word
```

it works.

But with foldr I always get an error:

```hs
deleteSpacesF :: String -> String
deleteSpacesF word = (filter(not . isSpace) . unwords . foldr (\(x:xs) acc -> (toUpper x) : xs : acc) [] . words) word
```

I have also tried `(\x acc -> (toUpper (head x)):(tail x):acc)`

The error is:

> • Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
> Expected: String
> Actual: Char
> • In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘(toUpper x)’
> In the expression: (toUpper x) : xs : acc
> In the first argument of ‘foldr’, namely
> ‘(\ (x : xs) acc -> (toUpper x) : xs : acc)’

Comment: `x` is a `Char`, not a `String`, so `head x` and `tail x`, make no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is a `Char`, not a `String`, so `head x` and `tail x`, make no sense. You use `x` as the head and `xs` as the tail, so.

Here it thus looks like:

```
deleteSpacesF :: String -> String
deleteSpacesF = concat . foldr (\(x:xs) -> ((toUpper x : xs) :)) [] . words
```

you can also omit the `concat` with:

```
deleteSpacesF :: String -> String
deleteSpacesF = foldr (\(x:xs) -> (toUpper x :) . (xs ++)) [] . words
```

Comment: But why does it work with map? I mean in my first example? What is the difference between them?

Comment: @zeppal: `map = foldr (\x -> (f x :)) []` it thus has an accumulator. In essence `map` just abstracts away that accumulator.

Comment: And is it the same to write `concat . foldr (\(x:xs) acc  -> ((toUpper x : xs) : acc)) [] . words` with `acc`?

Comment: @zeppal: yes :)

Comment: What exactly is the difference between `foldr (\(x:xs) acc  -> ((toUpper x : xs) : acc)) []` and `foldr (\(x:xs) acc  -> ((toUpper x) : xs : acc)) []`?

Comment: @zeppal: `(x : xs) : xss` makes a list of lists, where `x` is the element of the first sublist, `xs` are the remaining items of the first sublist, and `xss` are the remaining items of the outer list (`xss` is thus a list itself). For `x : x2 : xs` you make a single list with `x` the first item, `x2` the second item, and `xs` the remaining items.

Comment: So I actually have something like this: `[[1,2,3,4]]` for example?
After some thinking I came up with this idea`foldr (\(x:xs) acc  -> (toUpper x: xs ++ acc)) [] . words`. Therefore I don't need `unwords` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
process = concat . map cap . words
    where
        cap [] = []
        cap (x:xs) = (toUpper x):xs
```

This defines a helper function to capitalise the first letter, which can then be mapped over each word derived from splitting the original string.

Note that `words` will also treat tabs and newlines as separators along with regular spaces, so you may need to modify that if you only care about space characters.